# Computing SHA1 hash of a file in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, hash, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, sha256

I need to compute the SHA-256 hash of a file uploaded via ajax to Google Drive  in my appscript deployed as a web-app. In the server code, I am computing it like this:

```
function getHash(file) {
  var hashBytes = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  // convert raw bytes into a base16-encoded string
  var hash = "";
  for(var i=0; i<hashBytes.length; i++) {
    var byte = hashBytes[i];
    if(byte < 0) {
      byte += 256;
    }
    var byteString = byte.toString(16);
    // if byte is not represented by 2 chars it must be 0-padded
    if(byteString.length == 1) {
      byteString = '0' + byteString;
    }
    hash += byteString;
return hash;
  }
```

However, the computed hash is different than the one I get for the same file e.g. executing

shasum -a 256 myfile

in a bash shell. Is there something wrong in my getHash() function?

I'd need this function to work on any file type.

Comment: There is a `}` missing in front of `return hash;`, Otherwise it seems to be correct.

Comment: @SpiderPig: copy/paste issue ;)

Comment: The `getDataAsString` method can only be used on text files. If you want to use other kinds of files you need to write your own code for converting it into a string. To check if the result is correct you need to convert the file to a string in the same way before feeding it to shasum.

Comment: Your title says "SHA1", but only SHA256 is used in the body of your question.